# Error inflating class TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to display an `AlertDialog` but I am getting below error because of the `TextView` (code is given below). The dialog works fine when I comment out this `TextView` code.

Here's the TextView code,

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enter OTP"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"/>
```

Here's the Logcat error,

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
       Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 14 to dimension: type=0x4
```

Comment: show your java code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Show your activity class.

Comment: what is the value of @dimen/min_padding?

Comment: According to the error. The error is in `android:padding="@dimen/min_padding"' this line. kidnly check your dimen.xml, whether the value is in correct format

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `min_padding`

You should create `dimens.xml` in the `values` folder .And `min_padding` has value .

Like this .

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="min_padding">10dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: Could you check my answer ?Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

- `Id` is missing in `textView`
- I think you are not accessing valid `id`

  ```
  <TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Enter OTP"
  android:textSize="20dp"
  android:id="@+id/textview"
  android:padding="5dp"/>
  ```

Comment: According to the error, the issue seems to be related to the dimension set to the padding